# I have a bunch of anchor tags on my page with different reference URL's. How can I use queryselectorAll to select a subset of tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of anchor tags on my page with different reference URL's. How can I use queryselectorAll to select all anchor tags except for anchor tag pointing to a page?

Example

```
<a href='abc.com'....</a>
<a href='xyz.com'.....</a>
<a href='abc.com/ghtcj/jkfhjkf'....</a>
```

I want to select all anchor tags that doesnt contain "href" with a substring "abc.com".

I tried `querySelectorAll(a:not([href*="abc.com"])`. But this is not working for me. Can somebody please help in how I can solve this?

EDIT:
Ok I correct my above statement. `querySelectorAll(a:not([href*="abc.com"])` is working as expected. But I want to add to this query. If my anchor tag has an image element like shown below, when i click on that image panel, the events are not getting triggered as expected. Only if I click below the image, the events are getting triggered. Sample html element looks like this

```
<a href='abc.com'...><img src='h../abc.jpg' class = "image-panel"> </a>
```

Can somebody please help on this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your example only `xyz.com` is selectable because the other 2 are with` abc.com` , right ?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to add an event listener dynamically on a page load on all the anchor links that doesnt have "abc.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('a:not([href*="abc.com"])'))
```

```html
<a href='abc.com'>....</a>
<a href='xyz.com'>.....</a>
<a href='abc.com/ghtcj/jkfhjkf'>....</a>
```

Comment: I am trying to add an event listener on all the tags that doesnt have "abc.com". I am trying to do it dynamically on a page load. So when i use a:not([href*="abc.com"]) its not working for me

Comment: subarachnid answer is ok for that. But why don't use event delegation for that ? (but for what ?)

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to javascript and DOM manipulations. Can you please give an example on how I can do that. The constraint for me is I need to load a Javascript file on our home page and dynamically look for links like 'xyz.com'(basically outside our domain, if we assume abc.com is my home domain) and do some actions for the same. If you can show some example or point me to a documentation for the same, that would be helpful. Thank you